# I want to open 3 .bat files at the right time but I can't do this

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to open 3 different files using cmd (Command Prompt)
I tried

> "Start C:>FileName.bat"

but is not working 
I seen to much questions about this but i want to open a .Bat File.

Comment: You can open .bat files with a text editor (for example, Notepad).

Comment: Do you want to run the batch file? If so, you’ll need the path to the batch file, or you’ll need to change the command prompt to be in the same directory as the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

If by "open" you mean that you want to run the .bat files, then use the `START` command as documented in `START /?`.

```
START "title 1" C:\path\to\FileName1.bat
START "title 2" C:\path\to\FileName2.bat
START "title 3" C:\path\to\FileName3.bat
```

The example given in the question will probably overwrite `FileName.bat` because it is redirecting stdout using `>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to edit the file directly from cmd and you have a 32 bit SO than use:

```
edit "C:\name.bat"
```

If you want to edit a bat file directly from an other(for example for installer):

```
echo here your first line >> "C:\name1.bat"
echo here your second line >> "C:\name1.bat"
echo here your first line >> "C:\name2.bat"
echo here your second line >> "C:\name2.bat"
echo here your first line >> "C:\nam3.bat"
echo here your second line >> "C:\name3.bat"
```

Or if you need to start at the same time 3 files(for example) just do the fllowing steps:

1)Open *C:\WINDOWS\Tasks.*

2)Open "Add new task".

3)Select whatever you want to customize hour, day(s) and so on.

4)Repaeat other 2 times from 1 to 3.

5)Wait for the hour you've selected.

If you want to open a batch file ditectly into an other use:

```
call "name.bat"
```

Or as @lit said you can open a new window:

```
start "name.bat"
```

If your file name hasn't got spaces than you won't need quotes.
If you your file name has space like "My new file.bat" (without quotes) than the commannds `call` and `start`will become:

```
call "My new file.bat"
start "My new file.bat"
```

In these case quotes are necessary on the name because it confuse cmd andit won't work.
One other thing(last) if your file name has quotes like "My new **"**ultra awsome**"** file" (strong quotes are in the name the other 2 aren't) and spaces than it should become something like this:

```
call "My new """ultra awsome""" file.bat"
start "My new """ultra awsome""" file.bat"
```

Hope that I understood that this is what you were searching.